# AJAX - Complex user activation for login

Tags: ajax, activation

Now this may sound complicated but I have a page called `activation.php` where after the user has registered using my `reg.php` page, they get sent an email with their activation link - `activation.php` then a get method of k to make `activation.php?k=activation-code-here`

I made it so it returns the status of the activation, e.g - success of error.

On my `reg.php` page, I want to make it so it uses ajax to open a sweetAlert popup saying `'Activation Success'`. It will get the popup depending on if the users `'activ_status'` changed from `0` to `1` in the database when they access the `activation.php` page with a correct activation key.

**Here is my code :**

***Activation.php***

```
    <?php

    include('inc/conf/db_.php');

    $result = '';

    if(empty($_GET['k']) || (!$_GET['k']))
    {
        header('Location: login.php');
        exit();
        $result = 'Hacker Tried Accessing Auth Page';
    }

    $key = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_GET["k"]);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<?php

if (!empty($key))
{

    $query  =   "SELECT * FROM users WHERE activ_key = '$key'";
    $result =   mysqli_query($con,$query) or die('error');
         if (mysqli_num_rows($result))
         {
             $row       =   mysqli_fetch_array($result);
             if ($row['activ_status']!='1')
             {
                 $query     =   "update users set activ_status='1' where activ_key='$key'";
                 $result    =   mysqli_query($con,$query) or die('error');
                 $result    = 'Successfuly Activated, Return To Your Other Page.';
             }
             else
             {
                 $result = "Account Already Activated";
             }

         }
         else
         {
             $result = 'Invalid Access Token';
         }
}
else
{
    $result = 'Error';
}

?>

  <?php include('inc/login_header.php'); ?>

      <div class="accountbg"></div>
      <div class="wrapper-page">
         <div class="panel panel-color panel-primary panel-pages">
            <div class="panel-body">

            <br>
            <center><div id="result"></center>
            <br>

               <h3 class="text-center m-t-0 m-b-30"> <span class=""><?php echo site_settings('site_name'); ?></h3>
               <h4 class="text-muted text-center m-t-0"><b>Activation Status</b></h4>

               <br>

               <center><img src="assets/images/loading.gif"></center>

               <br>
               <center><div class="alert alert-info"><button type="button" class="close"></button><?php echo $result; ?></div></center>
               <?php return $result; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

***My reg.php page***

```
    <?php

    include('inc/conf/db_.php');

    if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) {
        session_start();
    }

    if(isset($_SESSION['user_i']) || isset($_SESSION['login'])) {
        header('Location: index.php');
        exit();
    }

    else if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <link href="assets/plugins/bootstrap-sweetalert/sweet-alert.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">


    <?php include('inc/login_header.php'); ?>


      <div class="accountbg"></div>
      <div class="wrapper-page">
         <div class="panel panel-color panel-primary panel-pages">
            <div class="panel-body">

                <center><img src="assets/images/loading.gif" id="loading-image" style="display:none"/></center>

               <h3 class="text-center m-t-0 m-b-30"> <span class=""><?php echo site_settings('site_name'); ?></h3>
               <h4 class="text-muted text-center m-t-0"><b>Sign Up</b></h4>


               <form id="registered_form" class="form-horizontal m-t-20">


                  <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                     <div class="col-xs-12"> <input class="form-control" name="email" type="email" required="" placeholder="Email"></div>
                     <span class="fa fa-envelope form-control-feedback text-muted" style="margin-top: 3%;"></span>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                     <div class="col-xs-12"> <input class="form-control" name="username" type="text" required="" placeholder="Username"></div>
                     <span class="fa fa-user form-control-feedback text-muted" style="margin-top: 3%;"></span>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                     <div class="col-xs-12"> <input class="form-control" name="password" type="password" required="" placeholder="Password"></div>
                     <span class="fa fa-lock form-control-feedback text-muted" style="margin-top: 3%;"></span>
                  </div>

                          <div class="form-group">
                             <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LeGFxYUAAAAAOqjyovTS3H0D1HS4IBgoHMvG4y_"></div>
                          </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                     <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary" style="text-align: center;"> <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="agree"> <label for="checkbox-signup"> I accept <a href="#">Terms and Conditions</a> </label></div>
                     </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group text-center m-t-20">
                     <div class="col-xs-12"> <button class="btn btn-primary w-md waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" id="reg_button" style="width: 100%;" >Register</button></div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group m-t-30 m-b-0">
                     <div class="col-sm-12 text-center"> <a href="login.php" class="text-muted">Already have an account?</a></div>
                  </div>


               </form>

            </div>
         </div>
      </div>

<script src="assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="assets/plugins/bootstrap-sweetalert/sweet-alert.min.js"></script>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function()
    {

    jQuery.validator.addMethod("noSpace", function(value, element)
    { 
      return value.indexOf(" ") < 0 && value != ""; 
    }, "Spaces are not allowed");

            $("#registered_form").submit(function()
            {
                if ($("#registered_form").valid())
                {

                  $('#loading-image').show();

                    var data1 = $('#registered_form').serialize();

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "inc/pgs/register.php",
                        data: data1,
                        success: function(msg)
                        {
                            $('#loading-image').hide();

                            console.log(msg);
                            if(msg == '')
                            {
                              swal({
                                title: "Registration Success!",
                                text: "Your registration was successful! Check your email and click on your activation link to be able to access your account. NOTE: Keep this page open",
                                type: "success",
                                timer: 15000,
                                showConfirmButton: false
                              });
                            }
                            else
                            {
                              swal("Registration Error!", msg, "error");
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: "activation.php",
                        data: data1,
                        success: function(msg)
                        {
                            if(msg == 'Successfuly Activated, Return To Your Other Page.')
                            {
                              swal({
                                title: "Activation Success",
                                text: "You can now login!",
                                type: "success",
                                timer: 15000,
                                showConfirmButton: false
                              });
                            }
                        }
                    });


                }
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>


   </body>
</html>

<?php } ?>
```

***I found a piece of code that might help me. It doesn't seem to be loading the modal up though:***

```
                        $.ajax({
                              url: 'activation.php',
                              type: 'GET',
                              dataType: 'jsonp',
                              cache: 'false',
                              timeout: 32000,
                              success: function(data) {
                                if(data == 'Successfuly Activated, Return To Your Other Page.')
                                {
                                   swal("Activation Completed!", "You can now login using the link at the bottom of the page - Already have an account?", "success")
                                }
                              },
                              error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                  console.log("Error[refresh]: " + textStatus);
                                  console.log(jqXHR);
                                  ajaxCall();
                              },
                          });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please clearly explain the problem you are having that is preventing the code from working as you intend.

If my interpretation is correct, you want to update the registration page that user keeps open while activating in another window, and then reflect the change on the registration page using AJAX. In fact, in this case you want to send data from the server to your client (you want something to change when a change happens on the server in the database). In this case, a simple solution is to repeatedly request the status (for instance every 2 seconds) using `setTimeout`. Other solutions exist but are probably overkill, such as long polling or web sockets.

Comment: Okay I will try that but I don't have any code. So what could / should I put in place ?